# I need help in-putting data into a protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried a " probable solution" I found here on this site but I get an error saying "Compile Error: For control variable already in use" the macro uses a button that has to be clicked for it to run.

My Code is as follows....

```
Sub Coa()
Coa.Unprotect Password:=Password
'
' Coa Macro
' create coa
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
    Sheets("GeneralFormat").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B:$B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("1", "10", _
        "15", "20", "25", "5", "30", "35", "40", "45", "50", "55", "60", "65", "70", _
        "75", "80", "85", "90", "95", "100"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("D6:O105").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CoA").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("E25:E25").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("GeneralFormat").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Sheets("CoA").Select
Coa.Protect Password:=Password
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet

Dim yourPassword As String

    yourPassword = "Password"

   For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Unprotect Password:=Password
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sheets("GeneralFormat").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B:$B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("1", "10", _
        "15", "20", "25", "5", "30", "35", "40", "45", "50", "55", "60", "65", "70", _
        "75", "80", "85", "90", "95", "100"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("D6:O105").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CoA").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("E25:E25").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("GeneralFormat").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Sheets("CoA").Select
' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Protect Password:=Password
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: You should remove your password from the code.

Comment: In which sub does this error occur?

Comment: thanks... error occurs in Button2_Click() subroutine

Comment: Looks like you're simply missing the `Next sh` on your first `For Each`

Comment: Now its telling me that my password is incorrect and that I should check if caps lock in on... Caps lock is off & I definitely have the correct password in the code and in excel

Comment: I have 3 worksheets in my file only 1 is protected do I have to protect all 3 sheets for the VB code to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
**'Delete this following line 
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets**
        sh.Protect Password:=Password
    Next sh

End Sub
```

You create a second loop with the same variable before you exit the first.

Comment: Now its telling me that my password is incorrect and that I should check if caps lock in on... Caps lock is off & I definitely have the correct password in the code and in excel

Comment: I have 3 worksheets in my file only 1 is protected do I have to protect all 3 sheets for the VB code to work?